# Script Listener or Alchemist DE?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting, script, javascript

what's the best listener for beginner scripting? I'm a little bit confused. Script Listener with CleanSL or Alchemist Dev version? Especially for Action converting and listening.

Comment: One is for JSX, the other is for UXP. You should choose based on the framework you use.

Comment: OK, thought alchemist can also produce jsx code? I won´t produce panels, only simple scripts. but scriptlistener has no WYSIWYG panel. a simple log on desktop. And I must run a second CleanSL script. And it records all the time. OK, there is a script to stop and start this.

Comment: I don't see a JSX option in Alchemist, but maybe I don't have enough experience with it. There's a way to start/stop SL via switching one boolean: https://pastebin.com/tvCY48b5

Comment: OK, thanks for the script. will SL run on PS startup? Or should I place this script in startup scripts folder.

Comment: This isn't a design question. Try http://StackOveflow.com